# How to delete rows with the same value? Merge column with same prefix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

**Hi everyone, I have two question need helping**

[image]
**Question 2**
I have df  with data as belows:

| ABC_x | Quantity silent | ABC_y | Quantity noirse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 05 | NaN | NaN |
| B | 03 | NaN | NaN |
| NaN | NaN | D | 08 |
| NaN | NaN | E | 09 |
| G | 01 | NaN | NaN |

How to merge two column ABC_x and ABC_y (same prefix ABC) to one column ABC, and merge data of two column special quantity to one column Quantity?

- DF expected:

  | ABC | Quantity |
  | --- | --- |
  | A | 05 |
  | B | 03 |
  | D | 08 |
  | E | 09 |
  | G | 01 |

**Thank you for reading and help me troubleshoot problem, Have a nice day <3**

I have try but unsuccessful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**

pandas has a function `duplicated` that gives you `true` for duplicates and `false` otherwise

```
In [40]: df.duplicated(["Column A"])
Out[40]: 
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

You can use this for boolean indexing

```
In [43]: df.loc[df.duplicated(["Column A"]), "Column A"] = np.nan

In [44]: df
Out[44]: 
     Name Column A Column B Column C     Column D    Column E  Column F
0  NameA   ValueA   ValueB   ValueC   Value_D001   Value_E01   Value_F3
1  NameA       NaN  ValueB   ValueC   Value_D002   Value_E06   Value_F4
```

and the same for the other columns.

Note

You can also pass multiple columns with

```
In [52]: df.loc[
    ...:     df.duplicated(["Column A", "Column B", "Column C"]),
    ...:     ["Column A", "Column B", "Column C"],
    ...: ] = np.nan

In [53]: df
Out[53]: 
     Name Column A Column B Column C     Column D    Column E  Column F
0  NameA   ValueA   ValueB   ValueC   Value_D001   Value_E01   Value_F3
1  NameA       NaN      NaN      NaN  Value_D002   Value_E06   Value_F4
```

However, this would replace only where all three columns are duplicated at the same time.

**Question 2**

pandas has a function `fill` to replace `nan` values. From your example I assume there is either a value in `_x` or `_y`. In this case you can use `backfill` to use `_x` if it is there and take `_y` otherwise

```
In [76]: df[["ABC_x", "ABC_y"]].fillna(method="backfill", axis=1)
Out[76]: 
  ABC_x ABC_y
0    A    NaN
1    B    NaN
2    D     D 
3    E     E 
4    G    NaN
```

Then do this for `ABC` as well as `Quantity` and use the first column only:

```
In [82]: pd.DataFrame({ 
    "ABC": df[["ABC_x", "ABC_y"]].fillna(method="backfill", axis=1).iloc[:, 0],
    "Quantity": df[["Quantity silent", "Quantity noirse"]].fillna(method="backfill", axis=1).iloc[:, 0].astype(int),
})
Out[82]: 
  ABC  Quantity
0  A          5
1  B          3
2  D          8
3  E          9
4  G          1
```

The `astype(int)` in the end is just because `nan` is not a valid integer, so pandas interprets the numbers as floats in the presence of `nan`

Comment: Thank you, but have some issue need question
At question 1: If have data duplicated at column but different Name, i want keep it not delete value. How to do it?

Comment: I don't get the problem. :( Could you give an example?

Comment: My mean: only delete value duplicated when same label at column NAME, not delete/(keeping) value duplicated when other label at column NAME

Comment: Example:
| Name    | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 | \n
| NameA  | 001     |   005    | 006      | \n
| NameA  | 001     |  007     | 006      | \n
| NameB  | 001     | 005   | 008 | \n
| NameC  | 005    | 007    | 006 | \n

Only delete value in NameA row2:  Value1-001, Value3-006
Value at row NameB and NameC keeping not delete in spite of duplicate value with row NameA
Thank you so much ^^ :D

Comment: I have updated question 1 by image add example and highlight my expected

Comment: I think I understand.
`df.loc[df.duplicated(["Name", "Column A"]), "Column A"] = np.nan` should do what you want.

Comment: Thank you @maow, it working
If I want delete multiple column (remaining columns), how to do it? or copy code multiple row :D
1. files_copy.loc[files_copy.duplicated(["TENBSCD", "SLCĐ_CT"]), "SLCĐ_CT"] = np.nan
2. files_copy.loc[files_copy.duplicated(["TENBSCD", "SLCĐ_XQUANG"]), "SLCĐ_XQUANG"] = np.nan
3. files_copy.loc[files_copy.duplicated(["TENBSCD", "MRI"]), "MRI"] = np.nan
Many thanks again

Comment: In your case because of how `duplicated` works you need to copy multiple times. Or use a loop of coure :)

Answer (score 0):

**Question1**

when column name have 'Column', chk duplicated to NaN

```
cond1 = df.columns.str.contains('Column')
df.loc[:, cond1].apply(lambda x: x.mask(x.duplicated()))
```

result:

```
    Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D    Column E    Column F
0   ValueA      ValueB      ValueC      Value_D001  Value_E01   Value_F3
1   NaN         NaN         NaN         Value_D002  Value_E06   Value_F4
```

make result to join to name

- full code

```
cond1 = df.columns.str.contains('Column')
df.loc[:, ~cond1].join(df.loc[:, cond1].apply(lambda x: x.mask(x.duplicated())))
```

```
    Name    Column A    Column B    Column C    Column D    Column E    Column F
0   NameA   ValueA      ValueB      ValueC      Value_D001  Value_E01   Value_F3
1   NameA   NaN         NaN         NaN         Value_D002  Value_E06   Value_F4
```

---

**Question2**

```
df.set_axis(df.columns.str.split('[ _]').str[0], axis=1).groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()
```

`result`

```
    ABC Quantity
0   A   05
1   B   03
2   D   08
3   E   09
4   G   01
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated question 1 by image add example and highlight my expected, i hope will reveice answer from you

Comment: @NguyenMinhTrung need code of example. not image